# Validating receipt with App Store in sandbox mode

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, app-store, in-app-purchase

I'm having some trouble testing my in app subscriptions.
To know where to start I would like to know if a recepit can be validated (in sandbox mode of course) even if it's not approved by apple. I get an error code which I can'r reproduce right now because of my next problem below:

Secondly, I get `Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=2 "Could not connect to iTunes Store"` a lot. It means `"user cancelled the request, etc."` according to Apple, but I didn't cancel anything!

Every once in a while it works though, even though I'm not changing anything. I read somewhere that this has to do with me purchasing the same subscription twice, is that true? I really need to test a lot and it takes sooo much time waiting for this error to go away, which makes testing a real cumbersome task.

I tried to go in to subscription settings when the App Store tells me that I already has purchased the product, but I can't seem to be able to log in there with my test user. I just get an `"Could not connect to App Store"`.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you testing on device or in simulator?

Comment: Device, purchases fails immediately on the simulator :)

Answer (score 0):

Right now, it may be because of the iOS 5 upgrading/activation stampede.

Comment: I tried creating a new test user and buyed one item with this one. Worked the first time (except my receipt doesnt validate). The next time i try it fails. Seems like it's to consistent for it to depend on the server updates. But what to I know! :)